# Ubuntu doesn't mount my disk on key?

Tags: usb, automount, fat32

I have a disk, it worked well but suddenly after formatting it to Fat32 using Windows, connecting it to my Linux doesn't mount it, what should I do?

This is the output of `lsusb`:

```
$ ls usb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6449 Microdia
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`mounting: mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist`

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 690.8G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]

sdc      8:32   1  59.6G  0 disk 

sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Can you post the output of command `lsusb` from Terminal?

Comment: post the output of lsblk in your question.

Comment: i posted the outpot of lsusb, lsblk, and of sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt

Comment: if it properly mounted on windows and display its contents?

Comment: yes on windows it mounts the dok

Answer (score 0):

Since USB is formatted with FAT32 filesystem, Can you mount it with this command?

`$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`

You may also refer to help for [Mount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount) in Ubuntu Documentation.